# RandomAccessFile access to /dev/raw/raw1 in java

Tags: java, linux

I created a raw device with:

```
raw /dev/raw/raw1 /dev/sda3
```

I can't access it with a `RandomAccessFile` in java.

```
File ssd=new File("/dev/raw/raw1");
RandomAccessFile randomaccess=new RandomAccessFile(ssd, "rw");
System.out.println("randomaccess file created");
randomaccess.write((byte)1);
System.out.println("wrote to file");
randomaccess.close();
```

When I run it with sudo so I have proper permissions, but it fails with:

```
randomacces file created
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write0(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(RandomAccessFile.java:489)
at Randomacces.main(Randomacces.java:23)
```

Is it because `RandomAccessFile` expects a block device but raw device behaves like a char device?

If I use:

```
File ssd=new File("/dev/sda3");
```

it runs without problems, but I want to disable the page cache. Is there any way to make it work or do i need to write my own device driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [raw(8) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/raw):

> Because  raw  I/O involves direct hardware access to a process's memory, a few extra restrictions must be observed.  All I/Os must be correctly aligned in memory and on disk: they must start at a sector offset on disk, they must be an exact  number  of  sectors long,  and  the data buffer in virtual memory must also be aligned to a multiple of the sector size.  The sector size is 512 bytes for most devices.

If you do not obey these restrictions the low-level [write(2) system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) will return EINVAL (Invalid argument).

You're going to have a tough time getting Java to issue correctly-sized and -aligned write calls given the many layers of abstraction in between it and the OS. The last requirement is particularly sticky: "the data buffer in virtual memory must also be aligned to a multiple of the sector size." No guarantees, but you may have better luck using `java.nio` classes instead of `java.io`.

Comment: `byte[] writebuffer=new byte[512];
  for(int i=0;i<=511;i++){
    writebuffer[i]=(byte)1;
   }randomaccess.write(writebuffer);`  gives the same error and i checked the sector size is indeed 512